# How can save rendered images to a specific folder?

Tags: animation

I tried to render an animation when it suddenly paused, I just thought it was lag so I went to my desktop to find each frame it rendered as a file (it flooded my desktop) is there a way to make it so it puts all of those frames in a folder.

Thanks

Comment: Is this question only about putting the frames in a folder?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to add the output folder name in the Output file path and add a backslash at the end. Then Blender will create the folder (if it doesn't already exist), and write the new frame files into this folder.

[image]

Comment: No problem. If this solves your problem, please mark the question as answered.